# Monitoring ASP.NET application memory and disk usage

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, profiling

What is the best way to monitor memory/cpu/disk (reads/sec or total reads) utilisation for an ASP.NET (MVC) application (or and app pool). Are there any perf counters that can do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built in ASP.NET performance monitoring tools (Which will give you the cpu utilization/memory statistics), you could extend this further by enabling tracing which will provide you with further diagnostic information.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xxk09t8(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You might be also interested in IIS's [Failed Request Trace](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and other ASP.NET related ETW sources. For example run on the command line: `logman query providers "ASP.NET Events"`, `logman query providers "IIS: WWW Global"`